Can I get the git hash from repo url?
I am working on creating a Jenkins job which takes a list of github repo url's as its input. I want to get the latest git hash from each of these repo's. But, I'm not sure how todo this without cloning each repo running git rev-parse --short HEAD. Does anyone know if there is a easy way I can fetch the latest git hash from just the github repo url?

Does this help? https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/commits

git ls-remote $URL HEAD

See the docs. Example:
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git HEAD
32c1ce111d56025594083a8c8889994f205acc9c        HEAD

For private repositories you need authentication.
